# mongo aggregate with array sum and $lookup sum

Tags: mongodb

**invoice table**

```
{ 
    "_id" : 123
    "dueDate" : 1494858422, 
    "invoiceLines" : [
        {
            "lineText" : "Rent Price", 
            "amountTotal" : 5000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount", 
            "amountTotal" : -1000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Final cleaning", 
            "amountTotal" : 500
        } 
    ], 
    "paid" : false
}
```

**receipt table**

```
{ 
    "_id" : 20,
    "invoiceNo" : 123,
    "amount" : 2000
},
{ 
    "_id" : 21,
    "invoiceNo" : 123,
    "amount" : 1000 
}
```

**The result I want**

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "dueDate" : 1494858422,
    "invoiceTotal" : 4500,
    "receiptTotal" : 3000
}
```

So I wanna add all `invoiceLines.amountTotal` together, and get all `receipts` and also add their `amount` together

Problem is that the result shows `invoiceTotal: 0`

Here is my aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "dueDate"  : {$lte: (1498988330)},
        "paid" : false
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "receipt",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "invoiceNo",
        as: "receipt"
    }
},
{
    $project:{
        "_id": 1,
        "dueDate": 1,
        "invoiceTotal": {
            "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$invoice.invoiceLines",
                    "as": "il",
                    "in": "$$il.amountTotal"
                }
            }
        },
        "receiptTotal": {
            "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$receipt",
                    "as": "re",
                    "in": "$$re.amount"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

I tried

```
{
    $unwind: "$invoice.invoiceLines" 
},
```

But then I get no result at all.

Comment: Collection name prefix is not needed. Try `"input": "$invoiceLines"` .

Comment: Veeram to the rescue!!  it worked.  This one was actually build on another crazy aggregate that you taught me. So I almost got it this time :-)

Comment: Ok Veeram, lets make it a challenge.  Lets say I want to add the `"lineText" : "Rent Price"` from the first `invoiceLine` to my  `$project`  - how would you do that?

Comment: Hmmm  `"invoiceLines.lineText" :1,` gives me all of them (of cause), but `"invoiceLines[0].lineText" :1,` gives me nothing.  is there a `$first` command or something I can use?

Comment: Try `"lineText" :{$arrayElemAt:["$invoiceLines.lineText", 0]}`

Comment: hehehe @Veeram - is there anything that you cannot do in mongodb?  :-D  Thanks.  Put a quick answer so I can give you credits.